# Why does the Nobel committee not award prize to collaborations?

Tags: collaboration, academic-history, awards

The 2013 Physics Nobel prize went to François Englebert and Peter Higgs, for their discovery of the Higgs boson. I was wondering why the CERN, as an institution, or the ATLAS collaboration, are not co-awarded the price with Englebert and Higgs. Apparently, “collaborations” cannot be awarded the Nobel prize. Is it a tradition, or something written in the rules of the Nobel foundation? Has there ever been an exception?

Comment: Why should they? I mean almost any scientist works in some company and why should this company also get co-awarded? It is true, that without the LHC, they would not have been able to discover the Higgs boson, but it is still an achievement of only a little team out of the more than 3.000 employees of CERN.

Comment: CERN was mentioned as the firs possible collaboration to get a prize. "First" in this sense excludes the Peace prize which has been given to "groups" since quite a while. There are no formalities that would prevent such group-awards.

Comment: Because when Alfred Nobel wrote his will to setup the prizes most science was done by individuals or very small groups where only recognizing the leaders was reasonable; not massive teams of hundreds or thousands.  Despite there being an institution or organization clause that would be reasonable for a lot of recent work it's never been used because:  TRADITION!

Comment: Isn't the IPCC (2007 winner) a collaboration?

Comment: @mankoff Yes and awarded the Peace prize

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In [paragraph 4 of the statutes](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_organizations/nobelfoundation/statutes.html#par4), it restricts the price to be only awarded to two works and to a maximum of 3 individuals.
But it also says, that it can be awarded to an institution or organization. Which has been done with the Nobel Peace Prizes to the EU.

> A prize amount may be equally divided between two works, each of which is considered to merit a prize. If a work that is being rewarded has been produced by two or three persons, the prize shall be awarded to them jointly. In no case may a prize amount be divided between more than three persons.
>
> […]
>
> Each prize-awarding body shall be competent to decide whether the prize it is entitled to award may be conferred upon an institution or association.

Comment: More precisely, it is up to each prize committee to decide if organizations can receive prizes. So a collaboration needs to be a self-standing organization to be eligible, it would seem.

Comment: So, if it's up to each committee, has the physics committee ever taken an “official” position on the matter? Have collaborations/institutions ever been awarded the prize?

Comment: As far as I can see, only the Nobel Peace Prizes has been awarded multiple times to an organization, but none of the other Nobel Prizes.

Answer (score 8):

Apparently, there might have been an [internal dispute behind Nobel physics delay](http://www.thelocal.se/50690/20131009/), on the possibility of including the CERN as a recipient. However, according to this article, some members of the Royal Swedish Academy of Science hint that it was not possible with the current rules:

- > “It was discussed a lot. But we must follow the (Nobel’s) will as I see it. There is nothing in it about institutions so in that way the decision was dead simple,” said Hans Ryde, professor of physics at Lund University.
- > The chairman of the prize committee, Lars Brink, defended the decision, saying it was a “theoretical prize”.
- > “Research is changing. If you go back a hundred years it was about a single person doing experiments and making discoveries. And today it’s 6,000 or so people – a sort of collegial research situation,” said Academy member Per Carlson, professor of elementary particle physics at the Royal Institute of Technology.
  >
  > “I don’t know if the Academy will open up the possibility to give the prize to organizations in the future – it’s a possibility,” he suggested. “In my view it should be possible.”

So even though a Nobel Prize can be awarded to an organization, it seems that the Royal Swedish Academy of Science does not consider this possibility yet.